# SQL table joins

Tags: sql

I am trying to use SQL to get results back from my database but I cannot get the query right.

[image]

Above is the entity descriptions from my database and I want to get back the information for the price of a product, the quantity, and the parts associated with it. The ProductParts table is a link table between Product and Part.

[image][image]

Here is the values in the ProductParts table and the result that I want back. I have tried using a cross join but I can't seem to get it correct, I keep getting results like this (below)

[image]

I am currently using this query

```
SELECT 
Product.Price, 
Product.Quantity, 
kit_name.PartID as "Kit Name", 
blank_name.PartID as "Blank Name"
FROM Product
CROSS JOIN ProductParts as kit_name
CROSS JOIN ProductParts as blank_name
WHERE Product.ProductID = 3 
AND Product.ProductID = kit_name.ProductID 
AND Product.ProductID = blank_name.ProductID
```

This is the result I get back

[image]

Comment: Do you want only a single row per Product, even if there are multiple parts?

Comment: Yes, I am after just the one line for each product, and to have both part id's on that line

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
    Product.Price, 
    Product.Quantity, 
    p.PartID AS PartID,
FROM Product
INNER JOIN ProductParts as pp
    ON pp.ProductId=Product.ProductId
INNER JOIN Parts as p
    ON p.PartId=pp.PartId
WHERE Product.ProductID = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple inner join between `ProductPart`, `Product` and `Part` would work:

```
SELECT 
    prod.Price, 
    prod.Quantity, 
    prod.ProductId as "Kit Name", 
    part.PartID as "Blank Name"
FROM ProductParts pp
JOIN Product as prod
on pp.ProductId = prod.ProductId
JOIN Parts part
on pp.PartId = part.PartId
WHERE pp.ProductID = 3
```